# NDK general Segmentation fault, decStrong?

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, segmentation-fault

I am encountering a very wierd segmentation fault on android NDK, but it is not consistently occurring. I wanted to ask you guys on input, if there is none then i will try to report this as a bug.

I have a button press on an app tied to execution of C code. The button and C code works, but i have noticed after many presses, a segmentation fault occurs:

```
01-05 19:36:08.723  27256-27267/com.example.developer.addc A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xb8c80677 (code=1), thread 27267 (Binder_1)
```

I ran a stack trace using ndk-stack on the logcat output an saw this:

```
********** Crash dump: **********
Build fingerprint: 'samsung/klteuc/klteatt:4.4.2/KOT49H/G900AUCU1ANCE:user/release-keys'
pid: 28204, tid: 28217, name: Binder_2  >>> com.example.developer.addc <<< signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr b8dedddf
Stack frame #00  pc 0000d176  /system/lib/libutils.so(android::RefBase::decStrong(void const*) const+3)
Stack frame #01  pc 0001cfef  /system/lib/libbinder.so(android::IPCThreadState::processPendingDerefs()+82)
Stack frame #02  pc 0001db0f  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::joinThreadPool(bool)+42)
Stack frame #03  pc 00021965  /system/lib/libbinder.soStack frame #04  pc0000ea5d  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+216)
Stack frame #05  pc 00055f41  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+68)
Stack frame #06  pc 0000e58f  /system/lib/libutils.so Stack frame #07  pc 0000d298  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
Stack frame #08  pc 0000d430  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+240)
```

While the number of button presses required seems random, this error does consistently eventually happen. The native c code is:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <android/log.h>
#include "randomNumbers.h"
#define DEBUG_TAG "NDK_Tutorialapp"

jstring Java_com_example_developer_addc_MainActivity_getNumber(JNIEnv * env, jobject this, jint value1)

{
char *szFormat = "The random number is: %i";
char *randomResult;


int sum = randomness(value1);

randomResult = malloc(sizeof(szFormat) + 20);
jstring result;
if(randomResult!=NULL){
    sprintf(randomResult, szFormat, sum);
    result = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, randomResult);
    free(randomResult);
}
return result;
```

}

and randomness is a random number generator that currently is just returning a constant.

Anyone familiar with this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure here:

```
randomResult = malloc(sizeof(szFormat) + 20);
```

you allocate enough memory? `sizeof(szFormat)` will return 4.

Also what is `JNIEnv`? 
This sign `->` you typically use with pointers, in your case, you first dereference `env`, and then still applied `->`.

Comment: The way `JNIEnv` is used is correct at least - that's the way you call JNI functions in C. I.e., to call a JNI function in C, you do `(*env)->DoFoo(env, params...)`, while you do `env->DoFoo(params...)` in C++. But your comment about sizeof is quite correct.

Comment: @mstorsjo:I see. I am not familiar with jni. But the way it is used here, I'd use it if it were a double pointer ..

Comment: Yes, in C mode, `JNIEnv` itself is defined to a pointer type, so `JNIEnv*` is in fact a double pointer. It's all a bit of preprocessor hackery to have the same virtual table code work in both C (with a bit more verbose syntax) and C++ (where it fits in as normal C++ virtual functions).

Comment: @mstorsjo: yes, looked up a bit, so in C++ it seems it is just pointer

Comment: Thankyou @gio, good call. I made the change with strlen and it appears to be stable.